# How to decrease spacing between bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two glyphicons that I want to be right next to each other, but they have some space in between them, and I can't seem to get rid of it.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="authForm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <label id="authLabel" for="trash" style="visibility: hidden;">Trash</label>
    </div> <!-- end form-group -->
    <div class="form-group" id="authForm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <label id="authLabel" for="trash" style="visibility: hidden;">Trash</label>
    </div> <!-- end form-group -->
```

css:

```
.glyphicon {
    font-size: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#authForm {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrease or remove the **width** from `#authForm`.

```css
.glyphicon {
    font-size: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#authForm {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group" id="authForm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <label id="authLabel" for="trash" style="visibility: hidden;">Trash</label>
    </div> <!-- end form-group -->
    <div class="form-group" id="authForm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <label id="authLabel" for="trash" style="visibility: hidden;">Trash</label>
    </div> <!-- end form-group -->
```

Comment: Cant believe I missed that haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use span, form-group is required for html form elements.

```
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```